# Refreshing/Updating contents of a JTable from Database, after user interaction

Tags: java, swing, jtable, derby

I have been researching this for days and have tried everything I have come across, but to no avail. I have built an item checkout system in JAVA using a Derby Embedded Database and everything that I have wanted it to do works great. The only thing I can't get to work is having my table update or refresh the information displayed after the user (A) Adds a new entry in the system due to a customer checking out an item. (B) A customer returns an item and is checked back into the system. (C) The table data is changed/fixed due to a previous user error. Case in point: The user checks out an item using the check out dialogue box, then clicks the check in dialogue box but the new entry just made, does not appear. Closing out of the program and going back into it then shows the new information.

I have a method called loadTable() that makes the DB connection all the way through building the table how I want and returns the table.
So far I have tried:
- Calling the loadTable() on any event (Button pressed, window closed, etc).

- setFireTableDataChanged() method.
- table.setModel(), here I tried inserting the loadTable().getModel or using a temp table.
- jtable.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(jtable.getModel())).
- SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(yourJScrollPane); Ultimately it gets added to JSP.
- table.UpdateUI();.
- ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();.
- repaint().
- revalidate().

So far everything I have tried, does not produce the desired results.
I know you all will want to see code, there's a lot so I don't know what I should start with. This is my first time posting so, have mercy on me if i'm going about this the wrong way. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't call `fireTableDataChanged` from outside of the context of the `TableModel`, don't call `JTable#tableChanged`, NEVER call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI` or `updateUI()`, there related to the Look and Feel API.

Comment: From your description it sounds like the instance of the `JTable` you are trying update isn't the one one the screen - or you're not updating the `TableModel` properly, but this is all guess work as we have no idea what you are actually doing, because you've failed to provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. Oh and before you post "relevant code snippets", don't , that's not what we want.  It must compile, it must run, it must demonstrate the issue you are having

Comment: I got it! "..JTable you are trying update isn't the one on the screen..." you said this and it got me thinking. Turns out, I had this line: 
CheckIn checkIN = new CheckIn(); under my public class declaration. I made the variable global but moved the constructor call inside my jbutton actionlistener and it works! Mad props for the advice! Sorry I didn't post any code...

Comment: Haven't done that a few million times before...

Comment: Run Derby with -Dderby.language.logStatementText=true, and look in the derby.log. This will give you clues about what SQL statements your program is successfully issuing to the database.

Comment: Bryan, I did not know that. Very useful to know for the future. Much appreciated! +1